# How to reset simulator in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Where is the option to reset the simulator in Xcode 9?. I am not able to find the option.

Answer (score 5):

Although it took me some time to find out, at-last i found it in "Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings"

[image]